# Find duplicate object values in an array and merge them - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, duplicates

I have an array of objects which contain certain duplicate properties: Following is the array sample:

```
var jsonData = [{x:12, machine1: 7}, {x:15, machine2:7},{x:12, machine2: 8}];
```

So what i need is to merge the objects with same values of x like the following array:

```
var jsonData = [{x:12, machine1:7, machine2:8}, {x:15, machine2:7}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're looking for pure JavaScript, but if you are, here's one solution. It's a bit heavy on nesting, but it gets the job done.

```
// Loop through all objects in the array
for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {

  // Loop through all of the objects beyond i
  // Don't increment automatically; we will do this later
  for (var j = i+1; j < jsonData.length; ) {

    // Check if our x values are a match
    if (jsonData[i].x == jsonData[j].x) {

      // Loop through all of the keys in our matching object
      for (var key in jsonData[j]) {

        // Ensure the key actually belongs to the object
        // This is to avoid any prototype inheritance problems
        if (jsonData[j].hasOwnProperty(key)) {

          // Copy over the values to the first object
          // Note this will overwrite any values if the key already exists!
          jsonData[i][key] = jsonData[j][key];
        }
      }

      // After copying the matching object, delete it from the array
      // By deleting this object, the "next" object in the array moves back one
      // Therefore it will be what j is prior to being incremented
      // This is why we don't automatically increment
      jsonData.splice(j, 1);
    } else {
      // If there's no match, increment to the next object to check
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Note there is no defensive code in this sample; you probably want to add a few checks to make sure the data you have is formatted correctly before passing it along.

Also keep in mind that you might have to decide how to handle instances where two keys overlap but do *not* match (e.g. two objects both having `machine1`, but one with the value of `5` and the other with the value of `9`). As is, whatever object comes later in the array will take precedence.

Comment: hey thanks a tonne, that solves the problem :) currently the data does not have two instances of the same machine so that should not be a problem

Answer (score 1):

I like the lodash library.

https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy

`_.groupBy(jsonData, 'x')` produces:

```
12: [ {x=12, machine1=7}, {x=12, machine2=8} ],
15: [ {x=15, machine2=7} ]
```

your desired result is achieved like this:

```
var jsonData = [{x:12, machine1: 7}, {x:15, machine2:7},{x:12, machine2: 8}];
var groupedByX = _.groupBy(jsonData, 'x');
var result = [];
_.forEach(groupedByX, function(value, key){
   var obj = {};
   for(var i=0; i<value.length; i++) {
     _.defaults(obj, value[i]);
   }
   result.push(obj);
});
```

Comment: anyone with a simpler, shorter solution? ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
const mergeUnique = (list, $M = new Map(), id) => {
  list.map(e => $M.has(e[id]) ? $M.set(e[id], { ...e, ...$M.get(e[id]) }) : $M.set(e[id], e));
  return Array.from($M.values());
};
```

id would be x in your case

i created a jsperf with email as identifier: https://jsperf.com/mergeobjectswithmap/

it's a lot faster :)